# How to cross compile curl with ftps?

Tags: compiling, curl, ftps

The status of configure are as below.

```
curl version:     7.50.0

Host setup:       arm-arago-linux-gnueabi

  Install prefix:  /home/calvin/Downloads/ConnectedDVR/car_dvr_rdk/target/filesys/opt/dvr

  Compiler:        /home/byron/Downloads/ConnectedDVR/car_dvr_rdk/../ti_tools/linux_devkit/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc

  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)

  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)

  zlib support:     enabled

  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)

  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)

  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)

  IPv6 support:     enabled

  Unix sockets support: enabled

  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})

  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes

  Built-in manual:  enabled

  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)

  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)

  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)

  ca cert bundle:   no

  ca cert path:     no

  ca fallback:      no

  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)

  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)

  RTSP support:     enabled

  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)

  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)

  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)

  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)

  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
```

It seemed to support `ftps`.
But when I executed `curl -V`, it shows:

```
curl 7.21.2 (arm-arago-linux-gnueabi) libcurl/7.21.2 zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: Largefile libz
```

Anything I lost it? How could we check it?

Comment: You showed the configure summary of curl 7.50.0, but the output is from curl 7.21.2. You forgot to `make install` or the new curl binary is later or not in your `$PATH`

Comment: Thanks,I made it again and showed the status as below.
It seem to be the same.Where could we check it.Please help,thanks.

curl 7.50.0 (arm-arago-linux-gnueabi) libcurl/7.21.2 zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: Largefile libz

Comment: Hi Sirs,
Do you have any suggestions on it?